# WPF: MouseEvents blocked for a short perioid of time after keystroke

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, blocking, keyevent

"Resolved", Thanks for input

i cant figure this out.
After i press the keyboard (With or without attatching event handlers for keystrokes)
MouseEvents gets blocked for a short period of time.

-Modifier keys does not block the mouse events (ctrl, shift...)

So what happends is, if i press like 'A', and press the mouse on some control, it does not register. (It takes somewhere between 500ms to 1s for the mouseclicks to register again)

Anyone else experienced this? Is there a workaround?
Iv tried hooking onto PreviewKeyDown and Up on all my contols/windows and done e.Handled = true, but no luck.

Kind Regards Tor Einar

Comment: To me it sounds like your code has somewhere some keyboard-input related event handling running in the GUI thread which does some heavy/long processing, and therefore freezes the GUI (including input-related event handling) until it finishes execution.

Comment: A quick way to find out is to press the Pause button of the debugger right after you pressed 'A' (you might need to try several times to get it right...). Then, in the debugger check the state of the threads - especially the GUI thread - and which code/function they are executing at that time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, Tough i think its something else that is interfering. Im gone test on other computer when i get time. I tried some of my other wpf apps and it happends there aswell. (MouseOver event is working, but the click is not registering). I can do multiple keystrokes in a row and all registers.

Comment: Okey, this is abit embarrassing, its my Lenovo that has some wierd thing going on with the mousepad and the keyboard. When i attatched a exetrnal mouse everything works perfectly :)